# htaccess redirect all images to different location and put image name in new url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is the rewrite rule that I am working with:

```
RewriteRule (.*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ http://www.newurl.com/?image=$1
```

What I want is all images to get redirected to the new location and this above rule works paritally.  The problem is that $1 will contain the whole url from the old request and not just the filename.  I only need the filename and everything that I try doesnt seem to work properly.  Any help is appreciated.

I think i've figured it out. If anyone has any other solutions though, please don't hesitate to add them.  Thanks.

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ http://www.newurl.com/$2
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you have figured it out: please create an anwser to your own question and accept it. BTW : $1, $2, $3 are created for every () you have in your regex. So if you use : `.*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)` you can have $1 for your parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually this rule will be better for you:

```
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ http://www.newurl.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

It is better to match just the image name rather than full REQUEST_URI thus removal of start of text character `^`

[R Flag documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)