# How to redirect from image path

Tags: facebook, redirect, amazon-s3

I'm using the Facebook Sharer snippet to allow users to share a specific post to their Facebook page. It's sharing a dynamic image passed into the FB Sharer (not the main url), so the image is www.site.com/path/to/image.jpg - when the user clicks on it from the actual Facebook post, as expected, it routes to that www.site.com/path/to/image.jpg.

My question is can I set up a redirect to ALWAYS send to the index.html page whenever the www.site.com/path is hit? I was thinking I could use javascript to redirect, but you can't fire javascript on a .jpg page. Is this an htaccess thing? If so, I have no idea how to go about that either. I am using Amazon S3 with Cloudfront.

Here is the FB Sharer -

```
window.open(http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=${root}&t=${title})
```

This is working correctly, but looking for help on how to redirect any page that has a /path/ after www.site.com

Comment: you should not share image urls, but real urls with the image as og tag instead.

Comment: ...that being said, i just generated an answer by combining 2 different stackoverflow threads i found with google.

Comment: @luschn I agree, but I need to be able to share dynamic images (aka an image the user picks) and I can't seem to find anything on dynamic og:image tags.

Comment: og tags should not be dynamic anyway, they get cached by facebook and will be locked after a while. you can still use dynamic urls though, with dynamic images.

Answer (score 0):

This could work - you need to exclude the Facebook Crawler:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/[0-9]
RewriteRule ^path/to/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ http://www.newurl.com [R=301,L,NC]
```

Sources:

- [htaccess redirect all images to different location and put image name in new url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697727/htaccess-redirect-all-images-to-different-location-and-put-image-name-in-new-url)
- [Exempt Facebook Crawler from .htaccess redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164861/exempt-facebook-crawler-from-htaccess-redirect)

I tested it here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

---

Although, the ideal/usual way is NOT to share images directly, but URLs with the image as `og:image` tag.